# get facebook status

Tags: facebook

I'm looking for a good, simple PHP or JS function to get my latest Facebook status updates. Anyone have a good solution?

I had a JS script but simply stop working.

heres the code:
[view code](http://www.anamoura.com.pt/ajax-facebook.html)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ad link) 404...

Comment: Fixed the link, it had an extra / ... but I don't see what this has to do with WordPress.  You're just using JS code ... vote to close and migrate to Stack Overflow ...

Comment: Where is your WordPress question?

Answer (score 2):

There is no real "easy" way to do it anymore, due to Facebook's requirements for an application and an access token and OAuth and so on.

The latest version of my [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) plugin has a working User Status Widget in the widgets module. It can display the latest status for a user in the sidebar or in any widgets area of the theme.

Setting it up requires creating a Facebook Application for your site. This is not a minor task, but it's fairly straightforward.